# Selecting only strings with 2 words in vector via regex

Tags: r, regex

I have a simple character string like:

```
test<-c("two words", "three more words", "something else", "this has a lot of words", "more of this", "pick me")
```

I would need a function that returns the indices of `test` where there are only 2 words in the element (in this example this would be index 1, 3 and 6, but 2, 4 and 5 are completely uninteresting). More context: I am searching for "real" names of persons among a large vector that is mixed also with company names (which have often 3 or more words). I have no clue how to perhaps get regex (or any other technique) to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to match the word (`\\w+`) followed by a space followed by other word (`\\w+`) from the start (`^`) to end (`$`) of the string

```
grep("^\\w+ \\w+$", test)
[#1] 1 3 6
```

---

Or with `str_count`

```
library(stringr)
which(str_count(test, "\\w+") == 2)
#[1] 1 3 6
```

Comment: Thank you very much - this totally solved my problem! Also the second solution works well! Also I learned something new!

Answer (score 1):

One option involving `stringr` could be.

```
which(is.na(word(test, 1, 3, fixed(" "))))

[1] 1 3 6
```

Comment: I was just going to post that. Note, `word` is from `stringr`

Comment: @Sotos oh, I was sure that it is from `stringi`! Thank you for noticing it :)